# split big json files into small pieces without breaking the format

Tags: json, scala, shell, apache-spark, databricks

I'm using spark.read() to read a big json file on databricks. And it failed due to: **spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting** after a long time of runing.I assumed it is because the file is too big, so i decided to split it. So I used command:

```
split -b 100m -a 1 test.json
```

This actually split my files into small pieces and I can now read that on databricks. But then I found what I got is a set of null values. I think that is because i splitted the file only by the size,and some files might become files that are not in json format. For example , i might get something like this in the end of a file.

```
{"id":aefae3,......
```

Then it can't be read by spark.read.format("json").So is there any way i can seperate the json file into small pieces without breaking the json format?

Comment: And i tried using java to solve the problem, but it showed java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when a I using readLine of bufferedReader.

Comment: What's the format of the JSON? Spark's default JSON reader works best if each line is a distinct JSON document so the file can be split. The fact that the file is too big shouldn't be an issue since it will read it distributed across the executors. If instead you're trying to read it as 1 whole document then, yes it could be larger than a single executor JVM can read in. In that case you could try to use a larger instance size with more memory.